# MacOS > Virtualbox > Centos 7.7 how to set ip/obtain IP

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, centos7

I am working under mac and currently setting up Centos 7.7 on it to run apache/mysql configuration for demo tests. I have set the network to a "Bridge Adapter" but I am not able to access the mysql or other setup (like info.php) that is set on the CentOs 7.7 (VirtualMachine). I looked further and saw that I need to edit '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3' and changed the following details:

```
"BOOTPROTO="   to a static address, but I am having hard time on setting the
"IPADDR="      (tried setting like 198.51.100.5 - random IP)
"PREFIX="      (probably 24 not sure)
"GATEWAY="     (set 198.51.100.1 also random)
```

from which most likely is coming the issue. Also I had to comment the

```
"NETMASK="     since from what I was able to see over the net it is replaced by 'GATEWAY'.
```

There is network on the CentoS 7.7 but I wish to connect from the mac to the centos on IP (locally) in order to perform test setups, any assistance with the configuration will be of help.

Also I have already added the ports using firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port= commands

Comment: hi Vasil, i think this kind of question better to be asked in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). however, you should first try to ping your host os (the mac) from the guest one (centos) and vice versa. see if the ping does work or not, if it isnt, then the networking might be the problem. personally i always use Host-only combined with NAT (if i need internet connection) to make things easier.

Comment: @BagusTesa could you please give more details on how exactly to ping the mac vs centos (virtual machine) and vice versa. Also on the Network I have tried NAT and Bridge but no joy on that part.

Comment: NAT is only for facilitating connection to the internet, not your vm network. i also never had bridge working as expected. Host-only did the trick most of the time, even to bridge vm-to-vm networking on the same host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve:

In this case to resolve the issue I have:

1. Stopped the VirtualMachine.
2. Opened the VirtualBox > File > Host manager, from where I added a host-only adapter;
3. Changed the settings of the CentoS 7.7 image > network > added a second adapter with Host-only

Afterwards I started the machine and I was able to visit the IP/info.php and others.